# How do you install the Terminal app to an Ubuntu phone

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch

Other posters said that it should be available in the Ubuntu Store, but it isn't. If I search for Terminal, only five other apps show up which are totally irrelevant.

Thanks!

Comment: P.s. I am using a bq Aquaris 4.5, with Ubuntu 14.10(r21)

Answer (score 0):

Question solved. My phone did not even show the possibility of an OS upgrade because I was on a mobile data connection. As soon as I connected to a WiFi, I upgraded the OS to 15.04 for which the Terminal app (and many others) are already available.