# Cant find terminal app in Ubuntu store

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch

I got my bq Aquaris E5 today and I like it, but I cant find the terminal. I read on this site that I need to install the terminal app. But I cant find it in the store. I tried to change the phone into developer mode, but to no effect. Any suggestions?

[This is a screenshot of the search for "Terminal"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCsFq.png)

Comment: You can try searching for the terminal in your native language. For example, it is called "Befehlsfenster" in german

Comment: I have english settings, and "terminal" is called "terminal" in Norway as far as I know.

Comment: maybe you can try searching for it in the [uApp explorer](https://uappexplorer.com/apps). You should get redirected to the official appstore if you select "install" there.

Comment: Still does not work. It takes me to the appstore and shows the same result as seen in the screenshot

Comment: In [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/672606/how-do-you-install-the-terminal-app-to-an-ubuntu-phone) the problem was a missing update - maybe this is also the case for you

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-terminal/

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that I had an old version where the store did not have the terminal app, just as Wayne_Yux17 pointed out.

I connected to wi-fi and then went to:
system-settings -> System -> Updates Then wait for the update to download.
Then just press on the package to install it.

When the update is finished, the terminal will appear in the store.

Answer (score 2):

App search results are based on the frameworks your device has, architecture, location, etc… If you have an old image, and the app in the store requires a newer framework than is available on that image, it will not show up in the search results. You'll need to install the latest system update to get the new frameworks, to be able to install apps that require those frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

In the 'Ubuntu store', click on the magnifier icon (up right corner), enter 'terminal', wait a couple of seconds and here it comes:

```
Terminal
Ubuntu Core App Developpers
LIBRES 4.6
```

Further, just select and install it.

Comment: Hmm, I've done that, but the terminal does not show up as a result.

Comment: try sudo apt install gnome-terminal on your console

Comment: Console? Is that on the phone or do I need to hook it up to my pc?

Comment: No, you should not try to use apt-get on the phone.